# preg_match_all multine code scanning matches with a first word match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, php-7.4

first time posting a question here. I am currently writing a tool for reverse engineer PHP7 code in order to create UML class diagrams and for that purpose I'm using preg_match_all to extract sections of code from the source files. So far so good but I must admit I don't fully understand yet how regular expressions work. Still I was able to create complex patterns but this one beats me.

what I want is to match the use clause from classes body in order to get the traits names. It can be in one of these following formats *(as mentioned in https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

1)

```
use trait;
use othertrait;
```

2)

```
use trait, othertrait, someothertrait;
or 
use trait, othertrait, someothertrait { "conflict_resolutions" }
```

I don't care about conflict resolutions yet so I can drop these.

so far I have the following regex pattern:

```
class usetrait_finder {
    use finder;

    function __construct( string $source ){
        $this->source = $source;

        $this->pattern  = "/";
        $this->pattern .= "(?:(use\s+|,)\s*(?<traitname>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*))";
        $this->pattern .= "";
        $this->pattern .= "/ms";


        $this->matches($source);
    }

    function get_trait_name(): string {
        return $this->matches["traitname"][$this->current_key];
    }

}
```

which matches the mentioned cases, but I know it's a cheat because the "use" word must appear at least one at first. I wrote a PHPUnit test to check every normal case and the following test doesn't pass:

```
    // tag "use" must be preset at least once
    function test_invalid_source_2(){
        $source = "function sarasa( 
sometrait
,
someothertrait )
{ anything }
function test() {}
}";

        $finder = new usetrait_finder( $source );
        var_dump( $finder->matches($source)[0] );

        $this->assertEquals( false, $finder->more_elements() );

    }
```

the var_dump output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) ",
someothertrait"
}
```

my expected output should be an empty string or null since the word "use" is not the first thing matched on the first line. Of course others tests must pass, and in the $matches["traitname"] should be only one trait name.

usetrait_finder is here:
https://github.com/rudymartinb/classtree/blob/master/src/usetrait_finder.php

"finder" trait section of above source is here (not really important but it won't hurt mentioning):
https://github.com/rudymartinb/classtree/blob/master/src/traits/finder.php

full test case is here: https://github.com/rudymartinb/classtree/blob/master/tests/usetrait_finder_Test.php

thank you in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/S4nAme/1) help? Logic: 1. match the string based on regex. 2. Replace the `$2` group from the string. 3. Split on the basis of `,`(if present).

Comment: +1 yeap it does, it's just what I have done by removing the comma from the pattern and exploding the resulting strings into a new array, because I wanted $this->matches["traitname"] to contain only one name. how do I vote up your answer?

edit: that site is new to to me. ty !

Comment: I am happy to post an answer to your question and show you some improved regex syntax.  First I will ask you to provide an array of test cases for me and your exact expected output for each case.  When I have that data, I can construct the most accurate pattern for your needs.